# Java abstract primitive array addition

Tags: java

When primitive arrays given,

```
int[] iArr = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4};
long[] lArr = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4};
double[] dArr = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4};
```

And Each provided by Supplier,

```
class IarrSupplier {
  int[] supply();
}

class LarrSupplier {
  long[] supply();
}

class DarrSupplier {
  double[] supplyer();
}
```

How can I add them all in an abstraction way?
Such as

```
interface PSupplier<T> {
  T[] supply();
}
```

And providers are implements `PSupplier<T>`

```
class IarrSupplier implements PSupplier<int> {
  int[] supply();
}

class LarrSupplier implements PSupplier<long[]> {
  long[] supply();
}

class DarrSupplier implements PSupplier<double[]> {
  double[] supplyer();
}
```

I know primitive type generic is not supported in java.
And so above will not work at all.

But If it works, I hope to do,

```
// same or several type of PSuppliers will be provided.
PSupplier[] suppliers = polymorphsSuppliers();

long[] totalSumArray = [my_fixed_length];
for(PSupplier supplier : suppliers){
  for(int i = 0 ; i < totalSumArray.length ; i++){
    totalSumArray[i] += supplier.supply()[i];
  }
}
```

What would possible/better design to do this?

In short,

- Multiple int[] or long[] (or more summable primitive types data) will be given.
- I want to get grand total all of them.
- I want to make a long[] that accumulate all of each same index value of given arrays.

Comment: Primitives cannot be generic type arguments. You have to write separate implementations for each type of primitive you want to support.

Comment: @Andreas As I mentioned `I know primitive type generic is not supported in java.` I Know primitives cannot be generic type argument. And I ask How I do good `write separate implementations` and deal multiple implements : )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do exactly, but I can see several problems about your code.
I guess you want to iterate over an unidimensional array, so, in the interface **PSupplier** it's not neccesary declare the method that returns an array **T[]**, so the fixed code would be:

```
interface PSupplier<T> { T supply(); }
```

Now the next classes which implement from PSupplier interface, their generic type must be an array of the data type you want, for example:

```
class IarrSupplier implements PSupplier<int[]> {
    @Override
    public int[] supply() {
        return new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    }
}
```

Remember that the generics accept only Objects, and, unless in java, an array is an object, it doesn't matter if its type is primitive,so, for that reason, you can type **PSupplier<int[]>** and will be correct.
Or you can use **PSupplier<Integer[]>** and will be correct too, because Integer is a wrapper class for int data type. If you don't know about wrapper classes in java, I recommend read about that:
[Wrapper classes in java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-do-we-need-a-wrapper-class-in-java)

For the method **polymorphsSuppliers()** must return an array of **PSupplier**, for example:

```
** here, the polymorphism is working **

  PSupplier[] polymorphsSuppliers(){
    return new PSupplier[]
    {
        new IarrSupplier(),
        new LarrSupplier(),
        new DarrSupplier(),
        ......
    };
}
```

About your code in the for loops, I don't understand what you want to do exactly.
But I hope the examples I typed work for you.